# ath0 wi-fi connection breaks

Tags: freebsd, wifi, wlan, debugging, hostapd

Can't hold wi-fi connection in hostapd mode. Sometimes it's good, sometimes not, yesterday all day wi-fi works, today no chance even to connect.

```
% more /etc/rc.conf
wlans_ath0="wlan0"
create_args_wlan0="wlanmode hostap"
ifconfig_wlan0="inet 192.168.40.1 netmask 255.255.255.252 ssid whoknows mode 11g channel 4"

% more /etc/hostapd

interface=wlan0
debug=1
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd 
ctrl_interface_group=wheel
ssid=whoknows
wpa=1
wpa_passphrase=PASSWORD
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK 
wpa_pairwise=CCMP TKIP

% grep -v '#' /usr/local/etc/dhcpd.conf

log-facility local7;

subnet 192.168.40.0 netmask 255.255.255.252 {
  range 192.168.40.2;
  option routers 192.168.40.1;
  option domain-name-servers 109.194.160.1, 109.194.161.1;
  default-lease-time 600;
  max-lease-time 7200;
}
```

Tried without encryption, without dhcp - still connection drops sometimes on all devices (ipad, ipod, android)

Sometimes got:

```
%tail -F /var/log/messages

May 11 22:27:03 d15 kernel: wlan0: ieee80211_new_state_locked: pending RUN -> SCAN transition lost
```

And

```
kernel: ath0: stuck beacon; resetting (bmiss count 4)
```

How to fix? Or even get more debug info?
This behavior, started month ago without a reason.

Thanks.